# How can the central maximum in a double slit experiment have greater intensity than the original beam?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, interference, superposition

I have read in more than one place that the maximum intensity in a double slit experiment can be defined as the sum of the amplitudes of the light in each slit. For example, if the intensity of a laser is $X$ then the intensity of the light in each slit is $X/2$.

Furthermore, the maximum intensity will equal $\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}X\right)^{1/2}+\left(\frac{1}{2}X\right)^{1/2}\right]^2$ which equals $2X$. How is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think it's strange to have a higher intensity after light passes through some optical device? Even a magnifying glass can produce an output with higher intensity than its input.

Comment: We do not loose light. The photons of the stream get deflected and an artfully made slit (according to the used light frequency) give the result, we want. If zero distribution in some areas, than double distribution in an other line.

Comment: You get a photon distribution behind any sharp edge and bring edges **artfully** together one get slits and fringes. To get the best separation between dark and double bright lines one need a point like source from monochromatic EM radiation and the right slit width as well as the right slit distance.

Comment: @Clement Decker , why do you say the intensity is X/2 in each slit? are you talking about power instead? Power is conserved not intensity. And in the double slit experiment most of the light is absorbed by the screen between the two slits.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about conservation of energy, i.e. if your question is: *Since intensity is proportional to energy then how can the output have greater energy than the input?* then the answer is pretty simple. The energy conservation is not violated. You see, in the experiment, the energy is only *redistributed*. The energy that was supposed to be in the dark band region shifted to the bright regions. So if you take an average over the intensity they will give you the exact result as the input.

Comment: can anybody care to mention: why the downvote?

Comment: Answer is correct but irrelevant. I think OP thinks light on screen is more than emitted from 2 slits.

Answer (score 0):

Intensity of beam on screen is never greater than supplied intensity.

Let a source give light of 100 units. Let all of this fall on two slits and intensity from each slit is 50 units. This intensity from two beams redistribute and let form 50 bright fringes. Then intensity of each bright fringe becomes 2 units and *not* 100 units.

Whenever you read it in books, they either consider all light form single fringe or

they compare brightness of different points on screen.